# Should StackDBAs tweet meta questions?

Tags: discussion

I just got a tweet from StackDBAs linking [this Meta question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/sometimes-an-answer-is-just-plain-wrong-what-to-do)

Is the tweeting of meta questions something we want?

Answer (score 4):

I, for one, like having them tweeted. It helps me have secondary visibility on things I may have missed, like excellent answers on meta. (It only *seems* like I see everything).

Additionally, this is part of the core SE engine. I don't think any of the other child-meta's disagree, so maybe one of the community team mods may have more information. I'll ask them to poke over here (Thanks @Rebecca Chernoff!) and see what they say about if that's configurable. (@Grace Note says this is not-configurable)

What does the rest of the community think? Weigh in here!

---

From: [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92235/would-allowing-moderators-to-update-their-stack-exchange-sites-twitter-accounts/101340#101340)

Also, here's the criteria on what get's tweeted:

So just to clarify, [the SE 2.0 twitter accounts](http://twitter.com/#!/StackExchange/following) currently tweet:

- per-site blog posts (if present)
- chat events, if started by a moderator
- interesting questions on the site

Every **three hours** (on average).

Based on your suggestions, it's clear that we could do better here and tweet a more interesting variety of stuff from these accounts. We are now changing this to *also* tweet:

1. bountied questions
2. interesting answers of +3 or better
3. unanswered questions of +3 or better
4. particularly hot meta questions (not [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) though)

... and to do so every **two hours** since we now have a much greater range of things to "say" for each site.

Answer (score 4):

The Twitter account is for both attracting traffic, but also for highlighting content to existing users.  Not everyone is on the site all the time.  Some people might miss a great question or a great answer, and the Twitter bot highlights these.

The exact same goes with the meta site.  Those people that aren't on the main site all the time?  They're on the meta site less.  Meta questions, the governance of this site by the community, could always use more attention.  A casual user of the main site may not be aware of what is happening on the meta site, yet posts here affect them.  Meta discussions being fair game for tweeting is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for these reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the great insight!

Comment: so...it's not configurable? :)

Comment: @DTest, configurable?

Comment: @rebecca was just wondering if tweet behavior was adjustable on a per-site basis. I'm guessing not

Comment: @DTest according to GraceNote, it is not.